# Javascript setting cookie not working on Web Server

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Hi I am just a beginner and I am setting a Cookie to remember a user. When I have tested it, with just opening the file in my Browser(Safari) it worked fine, but after uploading it to my server (xxxxxx.bplaced.net) it is not working anymore. Here is my Code:

```
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + ";domain=xxxx.bplaced.net;path=/";
}
function getCookie(name) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
    }
    else
    {
        begin += 2;
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
        end = dc.length;
        }
    }
    // because unescape has been deprecated, replaced with decodeURI
    //return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
    return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}

setCookie('justacookie','testcookie',7);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: it is code for client-side, witch server language programing you develop?

Answer (score 0):

Client-Side setting and getting cookie:

```
//set cookies
document.cookie = "userId=jkadfa08da7f8f6a7fa";

//get cookies
function getCookieValue(name) {
     var cookies = document.cookie;
     var cookiesArray = cookies.split(';');
     var findCookie = cookiesArray.find(c => c.includes(name));
     var cookieSplit = findCookie.split('=');
     //cookieSplit[0] === name (key)
     return cookieSplit[1];
}
```

Server-Side(Node.js) setting and getting cookies.

first, install the cookie-parser library.

add to you server application the middleware like that:

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
```

then you will can get and set every API the cookies like that:

```
//get cookie
req.cookies['cookieName'];

//set cookie
res.cookie("userId","jkadfa08da7f8f6a7fa")
```

if you mean that you want to send them to server by request:
cookies are sub key in header, and every request you can send headers.

```
   axios.post('url', {"body":data}, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Cookie': yourcookie
        }
      }
    )
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can’t use node.js, any other way?

Comment: you can, cookies are subkey from header object. under key ['Cookie'], I used to like that but moved to cookie-parser, to set it easy mostly like the client but get is even harder than the client-side